# Eclipse Juno won't create Android Activity

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity

I downloaded `Eclipse Juno Java EE edition` and installed `ADT plugin`. I created a new `Android Application` Project from `Eclipse` and in the wizard I created an activity called TaskariActivity. After I pressed finish, it created the project but not the activity and the wizard didn't close. I pressed cancel. No activity or anything in the src folder. I created a new activity by right clicking on src, selecting `new -> other -> Android -> activity`. I selected BlankActivity (as earlier when I was creating the project), selected the earlier created project in the Project combo box. I set the `Activity` name as TaskariActivity, layout name as activity_main and title as TaskariActivity. Next I selected navigation type and I set it to `Tabs + Swipe` (I thought this would make me tabs and everything I had to do would be just inserting the elements and the actions for them). I pressed next, nothing happened. Finish didn't also do anything. I pressed cancel and an activity wasn't created.

So, how can I create an `Android application` like in the earlier version of `Eclipse`? It automatically created the activity and it was ready be run out of the box. Now it won't generate any files and the new activity wizard doesn't work. Help?

Comment: I have the same problem with Eclipse 3.7. If I create a project without an activity, it works but there are no files in src or layout folders (not much use!) If I select Blank Activity, then the wizard tells me, I need support library version 8. I already have version 9. Totally stuck now

Comment: Having the same problem, I don't get any error message the activity dialogue just stays. An entry for the new activity is created in the manifest but the label is not added to strings.xml and no activity is created in the src folder. I tried updating the support library, the SDK manager and Eclipse itself. I restarted Eclipse and still nothing. What is strange is that I can do it for some projects but not for others..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just go with default launcher image (blue smiley) instead of customizing it and it should work ;)

Comment: Not really relevant to the new activity wizard of an existing android project so it's not really a solution

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this worked for me: "Help" -> "Install new software" and install (this will update it) from this url: https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ I guess the Android website doesn't have an up-to-date version of ADT? Not sure where you're supposed to download the latest version from

Answer (score 3):

Workaround that worked for me (If you have installed support library>8 and still get the error msg)

- Delete the support library from the SDK manager
- Create a new project & install the support library by clicking on "Install / Upgrade"

[Check this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11262706/582571)

Comment: This give me a completely empty project, no sources or xml produced. Not really a solution.

Comment: The edited version didn't help either. By the way, the project explorer looks very strange. http://img832.imageshack.us/img832/1194/taskaritietokanta.png

Comment: have u restarted eclipse , BTW check out this http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859 this also mention the same

Comment: I found workaround(see comment 13): http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859#c13

Comment: cool , at the end you resolve your problem. Update your answer here

Comment: And how I replace the existing files? I have only one copy and it's not working.

Comment: @MikkoP, try to reinstall sdk or install it in another folder.

Comment: delete the old version before this?

Comment: Yep, I removed the SDK, downloaded it again and installed everything again.

Comment: I reinstalled the SDK, downloaded new one from Google's site. If I select Build SDK as 4.0.3 and minumum as 4, it works. If I set minumum as 2.3.3, it doesn't... But if I select 4.0.3 and 4.0, I can't select any navigation style or change the activity name..

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same issue by updating the support library (through the Android SDK Manager, it is located at the end of the list under Extras > Android Support Library) from rev.8 to rev.9!

After updating, Eclipse is now able to create projects as expected.

Comment: I think that the solution is just related with updating your current version, whatever it is (mine was 8), to the latest (which is rev 9). The thing is that apparently projects are now being created with the support library included when you set a lower minimum-sdk version, like 2.2, but only the latest support lib is included correctly..If you don't have rev9, I'd try to install it and see how it goes, if you already do, then I'm sorry, it's probably something else.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I could create the project changing the "minimum required SDK" to 3.0 Honeycomb.

What is the versión you have selected?