# Can not create new Android project in eclipse juno

Tags: android, eclipse

i can't create new android project. there is no "Android Project". There are android activity, android application project.... How i can create it?

Comment: If all sdk and other requirements are already installed then...

go thru this http://stackoverflow.com/a/17168035/1206052  to look for where option for creating android projects exist

Answer (score 1):

Do you have ADT plug-in installed? ([here](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html))

Answer (score 0):

Similar question [Eclipse Juno won't create Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260619/eclipse-juno-wont-create-android-activity)

see the issue: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=33859