# Creating new android project in Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, project

I have downloaded SDK to the Eclipse and installed the ADT Plugin but when I want to create a new Android project all I get is : File -> New ->(No Applicable Items).

How can I solve this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Have you installed ADT plugin too?

Comment: Yes i have, still showing me the same thing

Comment: A few things I could think of.. You may have downloaded an incompatible Android SDK or Eclipse.  Make sure they are compatible with your machine (e.g. that you didn't download the 64-bit SDK when you're on a 32-bit machine, etc).

Comment: @MikeGates I opened Windows -> New window and only there I could open new android project.

Comment: There is the chance that you're not on the `workbench` of Eclipse yet - you may still be on the only-displayed-once home screen.  Is this true?  I'm running out of ideas :(

Comment: @MikeGates I think it was that. Thanks for the help anyway, now its OK.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure that you are using the right perspective in Eclipse. Window -> Open Perspective -> Other...

Answer (score 1):

Click on new "project", then you can select what type of project. I myself could not find out how to, it is a confusing layout and a bit poorly presented. Once you pick the project you simply click on an "Android" folder of options and can start programming away. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

I used to work with `Eclipse Helios`

And in that it was straight forward

```
File -> New Android Application Project
```

In my new Company they Work with `Eclipse Juno`

and for `Eclipse Juno` I have to go little deeper in Menu

```
File -> New -> Project -> Android -> Android Application Project
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have installed Eclipse and the Android SDK, but don't forget about the [ADT Plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html).  After installing it, [these instructions](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html) are particularly straightforward in getting the ADT Plugin to work in Eclipse.

In general, [this link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/adding-packages.html) provides the steps to take following downloading the SDK.  Perhaps you installed it but never imported it into Eclipse (this link also encapsulates the second link I've posted when hitting "Next" on the instruction page twice).

Comment: I have add the ADT plugin and downloaded the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

change the workspace address. I got the same problem but it works after i change it.