# No main.xml file created by Eclipse/ADT

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have the latest version of Eclipse and the ADT. I created a new Android project and in the create wizard it asked me to create an Activity, I did. When the project loads, however, I don't have a main.xml file in res/layout. All I have is the activity.xml file for the activity I created. I even tried creating a project with no activity and I don't get the main.xml file.

Is this the way it should work now?

Comment: "All I have is the activity xml file for the activity I created" -- that *is* `main.xml`, if you choose to name it that. If you chose another name in the wizard, well, that's the layout file.

Comment: Open your activity and check what the line setContentView(R.layout.XXX)             says.

Comment: Sorry, was going through this tutorial: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html  and mentions all projects have main.xml so thought I was missing something.

Comment: Accept your old question's answers

Answer (score 2):

I think you have need to matching your installer version and ADT version such as installer-20.0.3 and ADT-20.0.3 .

Answer (score 1):

Answer is only targeted at **ADT R20** not to older ADT version

When ever you try to create your project with **NoActivity** then there will be no **main.xml**, **DefaultActivity.java** created by default & There is no DefaultActivity's entry in AndroidManifest.xml

If you are unable to create new Android project with default activity then here is the solution mention (only for **ADT R20**) https://stackoverflow.com/a/11260656/582571

Comment: I am creating it with an activity.  I'm following the wizard and am creating a new blank activity when I set up the project.  Once complete, all I see in res/layout is that activity. (activity_main.xml)

Comment: so what's problem ? that is your layout file which will be set as content in your activity.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the problem is with the default build SDK that is selected in New Project wizard (Android 4.1 API 16). Select API 15 or lower and it will create files just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I selected API 14 and I get the same result: no main.xml file. Just the activity_main.xml. I am going to assume that this has replaced main.xml?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newcomer in this business, but here is something I discovered using Android Studio, while I was following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project). On the Android Studio (New Project) Home screen, there are many options available, and among them, there are:

1- "No Activity": Your created project ends up without `activity_main.xml`, and without `MainActivity.java` as well

2- "Empty Activity": You end up with empty `activity_main.xml` and `MainActivity.java` files in your project directory, which I assume Android Studio creates by default for "Empty Activity" projects.

[image: Screenshot of Android Studio "New Project" Home Screen]