# Android : Eclipse Juno

Tags: android, eclipse, android-activity, eclipse-juno

I have downloaded [new SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and when I create an Activity xml file the Eclipse Juno doesn`t generate that Activity in res-> layout . How to fix it?

Comment: The Activity is generated in `/src` and its layout in `/res/layout`

Comment: I know it . but my problem is that Eclipse Juno doesn't generate it automaticly

Comment: Why do you need it to generate it automatically? Just duplicate one of your layouts/classes, make the changes, and save. It takes two seconds. :-p

Comment: "I create an Activity xml file" vs. "doesn`t generate that Activity in res-> layout" -- which is it? You are creating the XML, and you need to do that in `res/layout`. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260619/eclipse-juno-wont-create-android-activity

Comment: something like that question

Comment: Did you **check for updates**, after upgrading your SDK? I had a similar problem (empty project structure), and that solved it.

Comment: yes everything is up to date. can it be from that I have put the target sdk version Android L ? Sdk version 20?

Comment: It's an hazard... please consider that it's in alpha state. Lollypop will be in the wild not before next fall...

Comment: I think it's from new update . I looked in stack overflow several minutes ago and many people have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Juno works fine as I'm currently using it.

When you first create your project do:

**File -> New -> Android Application Project**

This should create the proper android file structure for you. Then when you want to create additional layouts, right click the layout folder under res, and do:

**New -> Android XML File.**

Then simply create your classes and reference the additional layouts. :)

Comment: I know that way , so eclipse juno doesn't generate Activities automaticly?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by automatically. This is how I've always done it as as all the pre-generated code in the class is useless and I end up deleting it all anyway.

Comment: When I chose New File -- Android Activity and after pressing Finish nothing happens , so I jave to create xml activity and class separately ? and then refer class to activity?

Comment: More than likely yes. This is how I've always done it. I would argue that doing it this way is a superior method than what you're suggesting. Having software "generate" files for you vs creating them yourself is never a good habbit to get into.

Comment: please vote up my question ))) I am losing my reputation