# Window that asks for activity name and layout name does not close

Tags: android, eclipse

When I create a new Android project in Eclipse. In the last step when it asks for activity name and layout name, the screen does not close when I click on finish. The project gets created in the Eclipse environment but does not load. Please tell me what should I do. Thanks.

### EDIT

I have tried the following solution but it does not work.
[Eclipse Juno won't create Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11260619/eclipse-juno-wont-create-android-activity)

Comment: `Please tell me what should I do` move to android studio since eclipse is not supported anymore

Comment: I cant move to Android Studio. I want to use html, css and javascript to make an app and phonegap tutorial lists Eclipse.

Comment: @FahadUddin so type in google "Phonegap with Android Studio" and read

Comment: I think you should use kepler because it works fine for me until you finally ready to move to android studio